# Tab not showing properly

Tags: javascript, css

I recently installed a module on my website, which adds a tab. This tab is not showing properly. I have figured out the problem, but don't know how to solve it.

Problem is that when the tab is activated, it has `display: table` CSS assigned to it, which makes it appear wrong. However if I manually change it to `display: block`, it solves the problem. When the tab is not activated, `display: none` is assigned to it, which is fine.

How can I make it show up with `display: block` by default ?

There is no code in the mod's source files which anywhere directly sets it `display: table`, not even through javascript. So where is this `display: table` coming from ?

`display: table`:

[image]

`display: block`:

[image]

Comment: what code are you using to enable / disable the tab? it would be set to display:table if that is what it were initially set to before it was disabled.

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

In one of your css files try to overload the style defined by the library/module generating the tab.

```
#tab-qa {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Note the `!important` directive and the concrete `#tab-qa` selector. This will ensure that the `display` property will be overridden even if it is explicitly defined via the `style` attribute or by any other less concrete selectors.